# How can I move all files matching a pattern into a folder?

Tags: command-line

```
ls | grep 'NC022.*nii'
```

Shows me all the files containing `NC022` and `nii`.

But when I try to move them using

```
mv NC022.*nii NC022/
```

It complains that

```
mv: cannot stat 'NC022.*nii': No such file or directory
```

This happens also if I try this (as seen in other answers).

```
mv -t NC022 'ls | grep 'NC022.*nii''
```

I am struggling to see what the error is, as I have the feeling of having done exactly the same thing numerous times without errors...

How can I move all files matching a pattern into a folder?

Example of partial ls output for first command:

```
NC022_Background1_Raw import  W325.39 L290.nii
NC022_Background2_Copy (2) of Raw import  W325.39 L290.nii
NC022_Background3_Raw import  W1103.50 L551.nii
NC022_Mask1_mask_air.nii
```

Comment: Remember that `grep` uses *regular expressions* whereas the shell uses *glob matches*. So for example `grep 'NC022.*nii` matches zero or more characters between `NC022` and `nii` whereas `mv NC022.*nii NC022/` will only move files matching `NC022.` then zero or more characters followed by `nii`

Comment: @ dessert good catch yes that is a typo. 
@steeldriver that seems to be the answer I was looking for. I guess if you could post an answer showing how can I match the regex in glob matches? I tried NC022*nii (to move files matching NC022 and zero or more characters followed by nii) but still no success..

Comment: @hirschme please [edit] your question to show some of the actual filenames (for example, partial output of `ls | grep 'NC022.*nii'`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing regular expression syntax (as used by `grep`) with glob patterns (as used by the shell).

In regex, `.` means any single character, and `*` means zero or more repetitions. So `grep 'NC022.*nii'` matches `NC022` to `nii` with anything (including nothing) in between.

In contrast, `.` is literal in shell globs, while `*` itself means zero or more characters. So `NC022.*nii` matches `NC022.` to `nii` with anything (including nothing) in between.

In particular, if you are trying to match all files with a `.nii` *extension*, the `.` is in the wrong place: you'd want `NC022*.nii` i.e.

```
mv NC022*.nii NC022/
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the issue was a little different. There was a space in the path, so we had put the whole path in quotes. Then the same error message `mv: cannot stat xxxx': No such file or directory` results. The solution was to omit the quotes and mask the spaces:

Before:

```
mv "/code/API Server/Data/*.rdf" /server/data
```

Solution:

```
mv /code/API\ Server/Data/*.rdf /server/data
```

Maybe this will help others who are looking for this issue.